# How to hide pagination from url using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, pagination

I have an original link:

```
http://example.com/catalog/catagoryname/
```

When I click on 2-th page, url like this:

```
http://example.com/catalog/catagoryname/1
```

Ok, how to hide number of page in the end url ?

Best regards.

Comment: You could send the parameter using POST.

Comment: "I can't speak english, but have to talk". So use another language: if you can't send the page number in the url, you'll have to use some OTHER method of doing so. but one way or another, you'll have to send that `2` back to the server, or something that represents "page 2".

Comment: You can try using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to convert `/example/1` into `/example?page=1`. Remember that a lot of 
[development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) have a robust routing engine that can do this for you automatically.

Comment: How using mod_rewrite ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you don't want to have anywhere:

`http://example.com/catalog/catagoryname/1` but `http://example.com/catalog/catagoryname/` but you want to use urls with other numbers `http://example.com/catalog/catagoryname/2`, `http://example.com/catalog/catagoryname/3` and so on. You don't need to do it in `.htaccess`. You should do it in your PHP code

Simple in place where you use pagination (you probably have loop for this), you should use condition:

```
for ($pageNr = 1; $pageNr < $totalPages; ++$pageNr) {
    if ($pageNr == 1) {
      echo 'http://example.com/catalog/catagoryname/';
    }
    else {
      echo 'http://example.com/catalog/catagoryname/'.$pageNr;
    }
}
```

Of course it's only sample, because you haven't put full code in your question